# How to view next with a button rather than a swipe?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I am using a [deck swiper](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper) to show data. Now instead of swipe to view next card, I would like to press a button to view next card.

Notice in [Methods](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper#methods), there is a `jumpToCardIndex()` but I am trying to implement a [GoToNextCard()](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper/issues/32). (Since I don't know current `cardIndex` from where I am trying to call the `GoToNextCard()`, so I can't use `jumpToCardIndex()`)

I am using the same [`jumpToCardIndex()`](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper/blob/master/Swiper.js#L310) but if I don't pass an index, I want it to just go to next card. So I did this:

```
  jumpToCardIndex = newCardIndex => 
  {
      if(newCardIndex) // if parameter exist, do old stuff
      {
          if (this.props.cards[newCardIndex]) {
              this.setCardIndex(newCardIndex, false);}
      }
      else
      {
          // else just incremenet
          this.incrementCardIndex()
      }
  };
```

The above works but crashes if I skip the last card of the swiper.

These are the main functions for this:

```
  incrementCardIndex = onSwiped => {
    const { firstCardIndex } = this.state;
    let newCardIndex = firstCardIndex + 1;
    let swipedAllCards = false;

    if (newCardIndex === this.props.cards.length) {
      newCardIndex = 0;
      swipedAllCards = true;
    }

    this.onSwipedCallbacks(onSwiped, swipedAllCards);
    this.setCardIndex(newCardIndex, swipedAllCards);
  };

  onSwipedCallbacks = (swipeDirectionCallback, swipedAllCards) => {
    let previousCardIndex = this.state.firstCardIndex;
    this.props.onSwiped(previousCardIndex);

    swipeDirectionCallback(previousCardIndex);
    if (swipedAllCards) {
      this.props.onSwipedAll();
    }
  };

  setCardIndex = (newCardIndex, swipedAllCards) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        firstCardIndex: newCardIndex,
        secondCardIndex: this.calculateSecondCardIndex(newCardIndex),
        previousCardIndex: this.calculatePreviousCardIndex(newCardIndex),
        swipedAllCards: swipedAllCards,
        panResponderLocked: false
      },
      this.resetPanAndScale
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're modifying the library directly in the Swiper component? If so you can just check if the index is less than the length of the cards available and jump to that index if it exists:

```
  jumpToCardIndex = newCardIndex => 
  {
      if(newCardIndex) // if parameter exist, do old stuff
      {
          if (this.props.cards[newCardIndex]) {
              this.setCardIndex(newCardIndex, false);}
      }
      else
      {
          if (newCardIndex < this.state.cards.length) {
          // else just incremenet if index isn't greater than length of cards
            this.incrementCardIndex()
          }
      }
  };
```

Also, you might be able to do this outside of the Swiper component library file if you add a reference to the component and grab the currentIndex and run the normal jumpToCardIndex(currentIndex +1) and just check if that index is less than the length of cards.

Comment: You are right and I think I should keep track of the index from outside the library. Do you know how can I "reset" the library back to original code? So I have made changes to the library while testing, but now I want to discard all changes and Ctrl-Z back to the original code did not work (I still get the crash even when discarding the changes that I made while testing). Do I download the library again?

Comment: And in your else statement, `newCardIndex` is undefined (since there was no parameter passed)

Comment: Sorry instead of `newCardIndex` I believe `this.state.firstCardIndex` is keeping track of the visible card index. Also yea, you would need to delete it from your node_modules and reinstall it.